# Limit of density of $X\sim\text{Gamma}(\alpha,\alpha/\mu)$ as $\alpha\to\infty$

Tags: limits, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems, gamma-distribution

We are given a gamma random $X\sim\text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\beta=\alpha/\mu$. Then $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mu$ and the pdf of $X$ is
\begin{equation}
f_{X}(x)=\frac{(\alpha/\mu)^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\alpha x/\mu}.
\end{equation}

**What is $\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}f_{X}(x)$?**

---

By central limit theorem, I suspect the solution is
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}f_{X}(x)=\delta(x-\mu).
\end{equation}

Comment: Look at the variance as a function of $\alpha$ and $\mu$.

Comment: @heropup Right. $\mathrm{var}[X]=\mu^{2}/\alpha$ so as $\alpha\to\infty$ we end up with a r.v. with $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mu$ and $\mathrm{var}[X]=0$ which means $X\sim\delta(x-\mu)$.  I was more interested in solving the limit directly, i.e. computing $\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}f_{X}(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
f_{X}(x)=\frac{(\alpha/\mu)^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\alpha x/\mu}\Rightarrow \ln f_X(x)=\alpha\ln(\alpha/\mu)-\ln\Gamma(\alpha)+(\alpha-1)\ln x-\frac{\alpha x}{\mu}\ .
\end{equation}
Use Stirling's approximation for the Gamma function
$$
\ln\Gamma(\alpha)\sim (\alpha-1/2)\ln\alpha-\alpha+\ln(2\pi)/2
$$
to conclude that
$$
\ln f_X(x)\sim \alpha(1+\ln (x/\mu)-x/\mu)+(1/2)\ln\alpha+\ldots
$$
Therefore, all depends on the combination $1+\ln(x/\mu)-x/\mu$. If it is $=0$ (which happens when $x=\mu$), then $\ln f_X(x)\sim (1/2)\ln\alpha\to\infty$ as $\alpha\to\infty$. If it is *not* equal to zero, then we know it is always negative (let's call this coefficient $-|\gamma|$), therefore $f_X(x)\sim e^{-a |\gamma|}\to 0$. So indeed $f_X(x)=\delta(x-\mu)$ (which is $=\infty$ if $x=\mu$ and $0$ otherwise).